# How to log Java Events to a text file?

Tags: java

How to log the Line logger.severe to a file. I just see it in the console.
BTW, may I please ask another question, is that how can you skip the row after the severe event, I tried to continue, but it just skips to the next column...
Thank you for taking time to help

```
  private Product2 readProductRow(XSSFSheet ws, int r) throws SQLException
  {
      Product2 p = new Product2();      


      try
      {
          XSSFRow rowData = ws.getRow(r);

          for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

            // read the first rcord
            XSSFCell cell = rowData.getCell(j);
            java.util.Date val = null;
            String value = null;
            FormulaEvaluator evaluator = ws.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

            if (cell !=null) {

                  switch (evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell)) {
                  case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                         value = cellToString(cell);
                                  break;
                  case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                         if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                                  val = cell.getDateCellValue();
                         }
                         break;
                  case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                         value = cellToString(cell);
                         break;
                  case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                         break;
                  case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                         break;
                  case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: 
                         value = cellToString(cell);
                         break;
            }


            if (value == null && val == null)
            {
               if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC && DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                   val = cell.getDateCellValue();
                   }
                   else
                     value  = cellToString(cell);
               }

               if (value == null && val == null)
               {
                   if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC && DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                     val = cell.getDateCellValue();
                   }
               }

               switch (j)
               {
                   case 0:
                      if (value == null || value.toString().trim().equals(""))
                      {
                          logger.severe("第"+  r  + "行纪录没有大类编码，没有汇入" );
                          continue;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          char tid = db.getCategoryID(value.charAt(0));
                          if (tid == 'X')
                          {
                                db.insertCategory(value.charAt(0));
                                Category tex = db.getCategory(value);
                                tid = tex.getCode();
                          }

                          p.setCategoryID(tid);
                          t = tid;
                      }
                      break;
                  case 1:
                     if (value == null || value.toString().trim().equals(""))
                     {
```

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable.

Comment: I wonder which jars do I include. I tried slf4j-ext-1.7.5.jar plus slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar plus slf4j-api-2.0.99.jar but I still need to cast the returned object of getLogger, is it an expected behaviour?

Comment: Don't worry, it's okay now, thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

skip to next row?  Use `return null;` or `return rowData;` to exit your function